# What is this rebus?

Tags: rebus

What can this rebus be translated to?

> goodgood memememe

Hint: The answer is a phrase.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess it is..

> Too good for me
>  (Two "good" four "me")

Answer (score 7):

After seeing @athin's answer, I wonder if too good two memes would work... :P

Comment: At first, I thought he meant to write to meme's instead of four me's.

Comment: yesssss same :)